# Angular 6 with Google sign in: How to redirect on success

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, google-signin

**What's going on**

I have a component which answers to unauthenticated users by showing them a Google Sign In button. When a user signs in the access token is sent to my server and it verifies it and returns a jsonwebtoken. I've followed Google's own documentation on how to implement the sign in and it's all working.

**The problem**

This is the first time I've used Google sign in, hence I'm a bit confused and not sure of how this is supposed to be set up. In my component I have the following click handler, which is called from the `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
...
    auth2.attachClickHandler(button, {},
      (googleUser) => {
        let accessToken = this.googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

        this.authService.authenticate(accessToken).then(res => {
          if (res.token) {
            this.authService.setToken(res.token);

            // I want to redirect to /dashboard
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');

          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          ...
        })
      }
   ));
...
```

But on success I want to redirect and Angular gives me the warning:

```
Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?
```

How am I supposed to redirect if I'm in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle?

**Further questions**

I want the user to be able to sign out on another page. But since `gapi.auth2` is undefined at this point, am I supposed to initialize auth2 once again? Meaning run `gapi.load('auth2', ...)` to get the authInstance and call disconnect and so forth?

Also, is `gapi.auth2` the equivalent of Oauth2?

Answer (score 0):

So I looked for ways to direct outside of Angular, and of course you have the `window.location.href` which works but it seems dirty. If anyone else has a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
this.zone.run(() => {/* my code here */});
```

Comment: add some description